# SharePoint restricted access document set not showing as restricted

Tags: document, folder, library, access

I've a problem with one SP 2013 library which contains a couple of folders with many document sets. All folders except one show "unique permissions" (key icon) next to the document set that I've managed access to.

Within one folder none of the document sets I create, after managing access, have the icon next to the name, which is causing me not to know the difference between restricted and normal document sets.

Any hint what could cause only one folder within the library to behave like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution myself so i will answer here.
The problem was that the folder was created as the "custom_document_set" content type that we are using in our environment instead of "folder" document set which should get applied when creating a folder. It happens during the site creation script that we have which causes the folder to retrieve the first content type from the list instead of folder content type. Creating a folder through file explorer does the same thing. 
If you ever come across this, click edit properties of the folder and make sure folder is set as the content type.
Cheers